# Creating component throught Anguilla Framework

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, gui-extensions

I'm trying to create a new Component using Anguilla Framework with this code

```
increment = 0;

var publicationId = "tcm:0-xx-1"; var orgItemId = "tcm:xx-yy-2"; var schemaId = "tcm:xx-zz-8";

var item = $models.createNewItem($const.ItemType.COMPONENT); item.setPublication(publicationId); item.setOrganizationalItem(orgItemId); item.setDefaultSubType($const.ComponentSubType.COMPONENT);

var onLoad =  function() {
    $evt.removeEventHandler(item, "load", onLoad);
    var schema = $models.getItem(schemaId);
    item.setSchema(schema.getId());

    var onInstanceDataLoad =  function()
    {
        $evt.removeEventHandler(schema, "instancedataload", onInstanceDataLoad);

        item.setTitle("Test Title " + (increment++));
        item.setContent(schema.getInstanceData(orgItemId, true));
        item.save(true);    };

   $evt.addEventHandler(schema, "instancedataload", onInstanceDataLoad);

    schema.loadInstanceData(orgItemId); };

$evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", onLoad); item.load(true);
```

and it is working well and create the new Component, but when I try to open it, always show the message "Loading" in his title... If I want to open it, I've to close and open the browser...

[image]

Can anyone help me?